# Preselective dynamic modelChoicefields Django

Tags: python, django

I have 3 models, which are connected by Foreign Key like this

```
models.py

class Partner(models.Model):
    partner_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    ...

class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    partner_id = models.ForeignKey(Partner)
    ...

class ProductData(models.Model):
    data_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    partner_id = models.ForeignKey(Partner)
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(Partner)
    ...
```

What I want is a form ProductDataForm, which adjust my choices for product_id by selection one partner_id. I had this forms.py above, but it doesn#t work :(

```
forms.py

class ProductDataForm(ModelForm):
    partner_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Partner.objects.all())
    product_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Product.objects.filter(partner_id=partner_id)
```

I need to work with this dynamic for normal Users and Admins on Homeage and Adminsite.

Can someone help me? :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a lot of experience with ModelForms or ModelChoiceField, but what I've done here might help:

```
class ProductDataForm(forms.Form):
partner_id= forms.ChoiceField(
    choices = [ (u.id, u.id) for u in Partner.objects.all()]
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But my problem is not the choices of partner_id. The queryset works well.
But the filter for product_id doesn't work

Comment: In this case what you want to do is update a field every time another field of the same form is modified. JQUERY/AJAX are made for that. The general process is to point to Jquery the field you want to monitor and every time it changes you call an url which will return raw html to update the 2nd field. But I feel that the good start would be not to start with Django/Ajax on this and keep it for when you feel more at ease with it;